Docker-compose Mysql is unhealthy
I am trying to setup docker for Wordpress core contribution, so when i am trying to run this below command to start the Docker container for wordpress-develop

npm run env:start

That time i am getting below issue.
Container wordpress-develop-wordpress-develop-1                                                                                                    
  Created51.8s 
  dependency failed to start: container wordpress-develop-mysql-1 
  is unhealthy
  node:child_process:965
  throw err;

Error: Command failed: docker-compose up -d wordpress-develop
at genericNodeError (node:internal/errors:984:15)
at wrappedFn (node:internal/errors:538:14)
at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:890:11)
at execSync (node:child_process:962:15)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/projects/wordpress-develop/tools/local-env/scripts/start.js:22:1)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
status: 1,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 10103,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}


Here is my docker-compose.yml file code:
  version: '3.7'
  services:

  ##
  # The web server container.
  ##
  wordpress-develop:
   image: nginx:alpine

   networks:
     - wpdevnet

   ports:
     - ${LOCAL_PORT-8889}:80

   environment:
     LOCAL_DIR: ${LOCAL_DIR-src}

volumes:
  - ./tools/local-env/default.template:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template
  - ./:/var/www

# Load our config file, substituting environment variables into the config.
command: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '$$LOCAL_DIR' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"

depends_on:
  php:
    condition: service_started
  mysql:
    condition: service_healthy

   ##
   # The PHP container.
   ##
   php:
     image: wordpressdevelop/php:${LOCAL_PHP-latest}

     networks:
       - wpdevnet

     environment:
       - LOCAL_PHP_XDEBUG=${LOCAL_PHP_XDEBUG-false}
       - XDEBUG_MODE=${LOCAL_PHP_XDEBUG_MODE-develop,debug}
       - LOCAL_PHP_MEMCACHED=${LOCAL_PHP_MEMCACHED-false}
       - PHP_FPM_UID=${PHP_FPM_UID-1000}
       - PHP_FPM_GID=${PHP_FPM_GID-1000}
       - GITHUB_REF=${GITHUB_REF-false}
       - GITHUB_EVENT_NAME=${GITHUB_EVENT_NAME-false}

    volumes:
      - ./tools/local-env/php-config.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-config.ini
      - ./:/var/www

# Copy or delete the Memcached dropin plugin file as appropriate.
command: /bin/sh -c "if [ $LOCAL_PHP_MEMCACHED = true ]; then cp -n /var/www/tests/phpunit/includes/object-cache.php /var/www/src/wp-content/object-cache.php; else rm -f /var/www/src/wp-content/object-cache.php; fi && exec php-fpm"

# The init directive ensures the command runs with a PID > 1, so Ctrl+C works correctly.
init: true

extra_hosts:
  - localhost:host-gateway

  ##
  # The MySQL container.
  ##
  mysql:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: amd64/${LOCAL_DB_TYPE-mysql}:${LOCAL_DB_VERSION-latest}

    networks:
      - wpdevnet

    ports:
      - "3306"

environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  - ./tools/local-env/mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
  - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

# For compatibility with PHP versions that don't support the caching_sha2_password auth plugin used in MySQL 8.0.
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "if [ \"$LOCAL_DB_TYPE\" = \"mariadb\" ]; then mariadb-admin ping -h localhost; else mysqladmin ping -h localhost; fi" ]
  timeout: 5s
  interval: 5s
  retries: 10

  ##
  # The WP CLI container.
  ##
  cli:
    image: wordpressdevelop/cli:${LOCAL_PHP-latest}

    networks:
      - wpdevnet

environment:
  - LOCAL_PHP_XDEBUG=${LOCAL_PHP_XDEBUG-false}
  - LOCAL_PHP_MEMCACHED=${LOCAL_PHP_MEMCACHED-false}
  - PHP_FPM_UID=${PHP_FPM_UID-1000}
  - PHP_FPM_GID=${PHP_FPM_GID-1000}

volumes:
  - ./:/var/www

# The init directive ensures the command runs with a PID > 1, so Ctrl+C works correctly.
init: true

extra_hosts:
  - localhost:host-gateway

depends_on:
  php:
    condition: service_started
  mysql:
    condition: service_healthy

  ##
  # The Memcached container.
  ##
  memcached:
    image: memcached

networks:
  - wpdevnet

ports:
  - 11211:11211

depends_on:
  php:
    condition: service_started

volumes:
  # So that sites aren't wiped every time containers are restarted, MySQL uses a persistent volume.
  mysql: {}

networks:
  # Creating our own network allows us to connect between containers using their service name.
  wpdevnet:
    driver: bridge

Also I tried to fix it forcefully by removing mariadb test code and by setting mysql host, username and password in docker-compose.yml file, so this mysql unhealthy issue is fixed. Below is the updated mysql code:
mysql:
       platform: linux/x86_64
       image: amd64/${LOCAL_DB_TYPE-mysql}:${LOCAL_DB_VERSION-latest}
networks:
  - wpdevnet

ports:
  - "3306"
environment:
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

volumes:
  - ./tools/local-env/mysql-init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mysql-init.sql
  - mysql:/var/lib/mysql

# For compatibility with PHP versions that don't support the caching_sha2_password auth plugin used in MySQL 8.0.
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password

healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "-u$MYSQL_USER", "-p$MYSQL_PASSWORD",  "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 20s
  retries: 10`

Though I fixed it using above solution but when i tried to  visit the wordpress site that time its showing "Error establishing a database connection". I also checked wp-config.php file and i haven't found any database configuration issue.
Can anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks
